# while loop getting second value onward not first value? PHP MSQL SP FPDF

Tags: php, sql-server

my while loop starts from the second value onward, it does not show the first value. Please any help would be much appreciated.

while loop statement shown below I am using FPDF to export results but I am not sure if this got anything to do with it calling 2nd value onward.

```
  while($dbRow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($dbQuery, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                $pdf->cell(0,10,'Impact for'.' '.$dbRow['Stakeholder_ID'].' is: '.iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", "£").''.$dbRow['Stakeholder_Return'],0,1 ,'',true );
        }
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at this line of your code:

```
if($dbRow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($dbQuery, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
```

You will see that:

1. It comes before your while loop
2. Hence your while loop gets the second row (since **sqlsrv_fetch_array** returns the next available row)

What it means that by calling **sqlsrv_fetch_array** in the if statement you increment the counter and with the next call you will get the 2nd row.

Solution:

```
$isFirstRow = true;

while($dbRow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($dbQuery, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if($isFirstRow){
         $pdf->cell(0,10,'Overall socio-environmental impact ratio: '.iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", "£").''.$dbRow['Schema_Return'],0,1,'',true );
         $isFirstRow = false;
    }
    $pdf->cell(0,10,'Impact for'.' '.$dbRow['Stakeholder_ID'].' is: '.iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", "£").''.$dbRow['Stakeholder_Return'],0,1 ,'',true );
}
```

You Can remove this lines as well:

```
do{
//...Code in between
} while ( sqlsrv_next_result($dbQuery));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I did the above and I got a blank screen, basically here (  if($dbRow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($dbQuery, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
  {  
$pdf->cell(0,10,'Overall socio-environmental impact ratio: '.iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", "£").''.$dbRow['Schema_Return'],0,1,'',true ); }
   ) I just want it to show one figure  but here  while($dbRow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($dbQuery, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
               
            $pdf->cell(0,10,'Impact for'.' '.$dbRow['Stakeholder_ID'].' is: '.iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", "£........ I want to show all values not only 2nd onward

Comment: I will update the code given new information. However, the blank screen as you mentioned might happen for too many reasons. Could you upload your code to pastebin after applying my edited answer (if you still have blank screen).

Comment: Blank screen no longer there however, it does not print any value now, do you still want me to put the code on pastebin?

Comment: Yes please. It will help me.

Comment: can I just put it for you only to see as I dont want to put it public please

Comment: I think it will be helpful for everyone to see it. I don't need full code just the part that you have already shown us in the post + applied changes. You can remove all sensitive data from it.

Comment: Here you can you see it now

Comment: Unfortuantely, I can't open it. It is a private paste.

Comment: I can't find my piece of code there. Are you sure you have uploaded the correct version?

Comment: check now please

Comment: line 195 you will see it there

Comment: Ok. Now I see the problem. You are preparing the statement but never execute it. I think you accidentally remove that part. if (!sqlsrv_execute($dbQuery)) {
        // echo "Your code has failed!";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }else{ //The code ... }

Comment: Bring that back and everything should work like a charm

Comment: I have done exactly what you stated and now when I generate the pdf files I get no results.

Comment: I have updated the code on paste bin also, btw thank you so much for taking the time to help me

Comment: any suggestion please ?